# Where can I find a high performance search capabilities in a Bitcoin node implementation?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, nodes

Where can I find a Bitcoin node implementation, which is capable of thousands of searches per minute, without degrading performance of the node?

I am aware of two Bitcoin node implementations.

- [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/download)
- [Bitcoin Ops btcd](https://github.com/bitcoinops/btcd)

I am looking for a BTC node implementation, which implements higher performance search capabilities, so I can search using syntax similar in capabiilty to SQL. I understand why LevelDB was chosen in the Bitcoin Core implementation (not sure what is used in the btcd implementation), but search performance does not stand up to my use case of executing thousands of searches (using bloom filters) per minute, [as described here](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/transaction-bloom-filtering/).

I have written a searchable database back-end using PostgreSQL, but its database must be pruned in order to archieve the high performance I require, which is not optimal. Thinking out loud, it seems like a NoSQL database like Cassandra, MongoDB, or the like might be better suited to this use case. But, I have not been able to find a Bitcoin implementation, which uses a NoSQL or comparable database.

With that that in mind, does anyone know of a Bitcoin, or altcoin, node, which meets my use case?

Comment: Perhaps you're not really looking for node software, but separate indexing software? The complexity of fully validating nodes is nontrivial, and part of the reason why Bitcoin Core doesn't have advanced indexing functionality is that it can also be provided by other software (e.g. electrs) which then doesn't need to perform validation.

Comment: That sounds like what I am searching for.  Googling a bit I found https://github.com/spesmilo, but I am not sure if there is an "official" source repo for electrs.  Do you know of one?

Comment: After a bit more googling and reading, it seems like you might be meaning ElectrumX? https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, I meant https://github.com/romanz/electrs. But there are probably dozens of other pieces of software that can provide various kinds of blockchain indexing.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. If you want to submit an answer for it, I will mark it as the selected answer.